# Make Triangle with Points

Tags: manim

I'm trying to use Manim to make a visual proof of the Squeeze Theorem from calculus. This involves comparing areas. I have made three dots labeled point0, point1, point2, and three lines labeled line1, line2, line3. The figure looks like a triangle, except I have no idea how to treat it like one. Namely, I need (a) to fill the shape with a color like green, and (b) to make a copy of the shape and move it elsewhere.

```
from manim import *
import math

class One(Scene):
    def construct(self):

        #Number Plane
        plane = NumberPlane(x_range=[-1,1], x_length=6,
                            y_range=[0,1], y_length=3, color=BLUE).move_to(ORIGIN+UP)
        plane_graph = plane.plot(lambda x: math.sqrt(1-x**2), x_range=[-1,1,0.01], color=GREEN)

        self.add(plane)
        self.play(Create(plane_graph))
        self.wait()

        #Creating the Triangles
        q = ValueTracker(0.7)
        point0 = Dot().move_to(plane.c2p(0,0))
        point1 = always_redraw(lambda: Dot().move_to(plane.c2p(q.get_value(),
                                                               plane_graph.
                                                                
underlying_function(q.get_value()))))
        point2 = always_redraw(lambda: Dot().move_to(plane.c2p(q.get_value(), 0)))
        label1 = Tex("$(\cos(x), \sin(x))$", font_size=30).next_to(point1)
        
        self.play(Create(point0))
        v1 = VGroup(point1, label1)
        self.play(Create(v1))
        
        
        line1 = Line(point0, point1)
        self.play(Create(line1))
        self.play(Create(point2))

        line2 = Line(point1, point2)
        line3 = Line(point2, point0)
        self.play(Create(line2))
        self.play(Create(line3))
        self.wait()

        v2 = VGroup(point0, point1, point2, line1, line2, line3)
        triangle1 = v2.copy()
        self.play(Create(triangle1.move_to(ORIGIN+DOWN)))
        self.wait()
```

The code above works to copy my "triangle", but I cannot manipulate it like one. I can't set the fill_color because there is nothing to fill. At best, I suppose I could find the area under the hypotenuse and force the color to be what I want, but that seems problematic.

Update: I used Polygon() with the points I described in my code. I think this is better. The triangle I made is of the same size and shape, but I think it's not using the coordinates/lengths of my plane and is instead getting the numbers from my plane_graph and using default coordinates/lengths of the screen.